# Automatically update local github repository on master branch change

Tags: git, githooks

I have a github repository that exists on several different hosts. I'm trying to figure out if there's some way to have two of the hosts automatically pull down any new changes to the master branch, without having to log in and issue the `pull` commands themselves, at the same time I still need to be able to push changes from those hosts on rare occasions.

From what I've seen I believe I should be looking at something with Hooks, but having a hard time understanding how they work. It seems like a server side `post-receive` may be what I'm looking for, but not sure.

Does anyone have any experience with getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git hooks will allow you to do extra things after issuing the `git pull` command, but not to periodically run a `git pull`. I recommend using something outside of git itself for this regular pulling. A cron entry to do this would look something like this:

```
* * * * * cd /my/directory/path && git pull >> /var/log/gitcron.log 2>&1  # Pull gitrepo every minute, logging output to /var/log/gitcron.log
```

Keep in mind, if you have a regular pull set up like this, a rebase or something else that rewrites history in your target branch will cause the machine with the cron to be in a broken state without manual intervention.

Comment: A cronjob might actually be a good way to go, is there a downside to issuing a pull as often as once a minute?

Comment: Nope. The internals of git make this a very efficient operation.

Comment: Great. I'll have to look in to `git pull` defaults and see how me making code changes on those specific hosts may impact the solution, but I definitely think this will be the way I go. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and created a python script with simple http.server routine.
Here the repository (only built-in libraries):
https://github.com/TinKurbatoff/github-webhook-autopull

Here you may setup a webhook:
`https://github.com/<github_user_name>/<your_repo>/settings/hooks`

and it will call your web server each time this repo is updated.

Even if you keep your repo copy locally — you may set this listener up at your home/work computer on some port and call your computer via IP (you may need to set up a port forwarding at the home router).